# .htaccess file with PHP MVC Framework

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I am building a website using CodeIgniter PHP MVC Framework, but am having troubles with the routing of the site. I believe the problem is with the .htaccess file that I am using. I have my site at `localhost/MyWebsite` and the `home` controller (default) is calling the `index` action correctly. However, when I try to go to any other Controller/Action (e.g. `localhost/MyWebsite/register`) route I get a Forbidden Access error. I have a Register Controller with an index action but they were not being found or something. Here is the .htaccess file I am using.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

What do I need to do to make it so all requests are routed to the index.php file in CodeIgniter so that the proper Controllers and Actions can be called?

Comment: I bet you need to activate +FollowSymLinks, search for it to find out how to add activate it on your Apache's virtual host

Answer (score 1):

Are you allowing override within Apache for your `.htaccess` file to take effect?

Paste the following code within `httpd.conf` configuration file from Apache:

```
<Directory "PATH_TO_FRAMEWORK">
    Option -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride all
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make share that your files or folder are owned by www-data (whether owner user/group), check with: `ls -l`

assuming that your OS is ubuntu
if it's not correctly owned then execute:
`sudo usermod -a -G your-username www-data`
`sudo chown your-username:www-data`